# Does $EXP\neq ZPP$ implies sub-exponential simulation of BPP or NP?

Tags: computational-complexity

By simulation I mean in the Impaglazzio-Widgerson [IW98] sense, i.e sub-exponential deterministic simulation which appears correct i.o to every efficient adversary.

I think this is a proof:
if  $EXP\neq BPP$ then from [IW98] we get that BPP has such simulation.
otherwise we have that $EXP=BPP$ which implies $RP=NP$ and $EXP \in PH$ 
now if $NP=RP=ZPP$ we have that $PH$ collapse to $ZPP$ and as a result $EXP$, but this cannot happen because of the assumption, so $RP\neq ZPP$ and this by Kabanets paper "easiness assumptions and hardness tests: trading time for zero error" implies that RP has such simulation and as a result also NP.

This sound like a basic result, 
anyone knows if it appears anywhere?

Comment: Why does $EXP=BPP$ imply $RP=NP$?

Comment: I guess EXP = BPP implies BPP contains NP, which implies RP = NP.

Comment: Right, EXP=BPP implies $NP \subseteq BPP$ which implies $SAT \in RP$  , via search-to-decision reduction, thanks.